# Where does RubyMine / IntelliJ Ruby plugin look for the "spec" directory?

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea, rspec, rubymine

Trying to add RSpec tests to a Rails engine project, I'm getting

```
Run Configuration Error: Rspec neither './spec/spec_helper.rb' nor
'./spec/rails_helper.rb' script found.
```

There's a [closed bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-16512) with the same error message, suggesting the problem was that one file existed but not the other, but (a) that bug's been fixed and (b) I've confirmed that both files do exist (assuming `.` is the project root).

I thought the problem might be the run configuration working directory (which defaulted to somewhere under `test/dummy`), but setting it to the project directory did not fix the problem.

I haven't had this trouble with any of my non-Rails projects, even those that use ActiveRecord. Where is IDEA/RubyMine looking for these files, and what aspects of project configuration affect that search path?

(Note: This is in IntelliJ 2016.2.5 with Ruby plugin 2016.2.20160811 on OS X 10.11.6. I assume RubyMine would have the same error.)

---

**ETA:** This may be an [issue specific to Rails engines](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-18841).

Comment: Might not be helpful but I can say that I'm using RubyMine and rspec and never had any issues. The spec folder is in the root directory of the application (containing both spec_helper.rb and rails_helper.rb). Doubt it's relevant but the only thing I ever need to do to configure RubyMine to work correctly when adding a project is add `gem 'debase'` `gem 'ruby-debug-ide'` to my Gemfile and set the "Ruby SDK and Gems" configuration setting to use my rvm gemset i'm using for the application.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are missing the Working dir

[image]